# Binary-Search Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Here is my code to find position of a certain element. And I am using Binary tree to store my Dictionary I want to know why it shows warning for Comparable-type. I have to use this in my project where element is a string type.

```
public int get(Comparable element){
    return getPosition(element,root);
}
private int getPosition(Comparable element, TreeNode root){
    int count = 0;
    if (root == null){
        return -1;
    }else{
        Stack t = new Stack();
        t.push(root);
        while(!t.empty()){
            TreeNode n = (TreeNode)t.pop();

            if(element.compareTo(n.value)==0){
                return count;
            }else{
            if(n.getLeftTree()!=null){
                t.push(n.getLeftTree());
                count++;
            }
            if (n.getRightTree()!= null){
                t.push(n.getRightTree());
                count++;
            }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparable is a generic class which expect type to be specified like `Comparable<MyClass> element`

Comment: (This would return the length of the path from the root rather than the position in an in-order traversal: you might need to _augment_.)

Answer (score 0):

The java generic typing parameters are missing `<...>`.

```
public int get(Comparable<?> element){
    return getPosition(element, root);
}

private int getPosition(Comparable<?> element, TreeNode root) {
    int count = 0;
    if (root == null) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        Stack<TreeNde> t = new Stack<>();
        t.push(root);
        while (!t.empty()) {
            TreeNode n = t.pop();

            if (element.compareTo(n.value) == 0) {
                return count;
            } else {
                if (n.getLeftTree() != null) {
                    t.push(n.getLeftTree());
                    count++;
                }
                if (n.getRightTree() !=  null) {
                    t.push(n.getRightTree());
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

However the algorithm seems not to be counting the leftish part of the tree upto the found element. However if position is not the index in the sorted elements, that might be okay. *(I did not check the correctness, as there is no early `<` check.)* If this was a home work assignment, "non-recursive with stack," rework a recursive version. Probably two nested loops, and a comparison on -1 and +1.